# Where can one find a list of Savage Worlds Explorer Edition publications?

Tags: savage-worlds

[Pinnacle](http://www.peginc.com/)'s [Savage World settings](http://www.peginc.com/games.html) seem to be making the switch to the Explorer's Edition size publications gradually. The Companions were initially published in the Explorer's Edition size. The current Savage Worlds rules were published in a full sized hard cover edition, and then were also published in the Explorer's Edition size later.

Where can one find a list of the current Savage Worlds books that have been published in the Explorer's Edition size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question was recently asked on the official forums, and the relevant post can be found [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34826).

In summary:

- Deluxe
- Explorer's Edition
- *50 Fathoms*
- *Agents of Oblivion*
- *Ancient World*
- *Apocalyps Prevention, Inc.*
- *Beasts and Barbarians*

  - *Golden Edition*
  - *Beasts of the Dominion*
- Companions

  - *Fantasy Companion*
  - *Horror Companion*
  - *Super Powers Companion*
- *Daring Tales* Compendiums by TAG (various genres)

  - ... *of Adventure* 1-4 (pulp)
  - ... *of Chivalry* (medieval fantasy)
  - ... *of the Shipping Lanes* (sci-fi)
  - ... *of the Sprawl* (cyberpunk)
- *Day After Ragnorok*
- *Deadlands*

  - *Deadlands: Reloaded Players Guide*
  - *Deadlands: Reloaded Marshal's Handbook*
  - *The 1880 Smith and Robards Catalog* (a Deadlands: Reloaded supplement)
  - *Ghost Towns*
- *Earthdawn*

  - *Player's Guide*
  - *Game Master's Guide*
  - *Denizens of Barsaive Vol. 1*
  - *Denizens of Barsaive Vol. 2*
- *Faith & Demons: The Rising*
- *Hellfrost*

  - *Hellfrost Adventure* Compendium 1 and 2
  - *Saga of the Frost Giants*
- *Iron Dynasty*
- *Judgment Day*
- *Last Rites of the Black Guard*
- *Mercenary Breed*
- *Necessary Evil*
- *Skinwalker*
- *Strike Force 7*
- *Sundered Skies*

  - ... Compendium 1 and 2
- *Suzerain Pocket Universe*
- *Thrilling Tales*

Comment: Wonderful! I will make an effort to update this list as we discover more.